# Not able to add Sun One web server in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, sun

I want to use sun one as web server in my web application using NetBeans.Here issue is when i am navigating to Tools->Servers and clicks on add server button only below 4 servers are coming in that list:

Apache Tomcat
GlassFish Server 3+
JBoss Application Server
Oracle WebLogic Server

when i am providing location of sun one srver its giving error like
The entered installation directory is not properly structured.
is anybody knows how we can add sun one as server? can anybody help me here?